# Convert BytesWritable to (utf8 encoded) String

Tags: java, string, scala, apache-spark, byte

Newbie to Spark. There are very few results when googling this conversion, which I thought should be a common action (read from sequence file & parse each line). I found two different ways to convert BytesWritable to String. Turned out Method-1 gives wrong results, any suggestions on the reason?

```
val lines = spark
        .sparkContext
        .sequenceFile[org.apache.hadoop.io.BytesWritable, org.apache.hadoop.io.BytesWritable]("file://"+data_dir)

//Method-1
val wrong = lines
     .map(_._2)
     .map(byte => org.apache.hadoop.io.Text.decode(byte.getBytes())) 
     .flatMap(parseEachLine)

//Method-2
val correct = lines
     .map(_._2)
     .map(bytes => new String(bytes.copyBytes(), 0, bytes.getLength, "utf-8"))
     .flatMap(parseEachLine)
```

If possible, please hint on why no one is asking this question. Does it mean this conversion is unnecessary(and if true, how to split the lines & create DataFrame then)?